# Searching occurrences in 2D list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2D list and I am trying to find the occurrence of the word 'the' in the list.

I am self learning python and try the following code

```
data = [["the cat is fed", "the bar is barred", "cat is now a bar"],
        ["the cat was fed", "the bar was barred", "cat was now a bar"]]

whatIsTheSum = sum('the' in s for s in data)

print(whatIsTheSum)
```

I am expecting a result of 4 but the program return 0.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your expected result if one of the strings contains "the" multiple times? `in` just checks that at least one occurrence exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't iterate over the nested array

```
whatIsTheSum = sum('the' in s for nested in data for s in nested)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the elements of the two different arrays. Try this:

```
whatIsTheSum = sum('the' in s for s in data[0]+data[1])
print(whatIsTheSum)
```